# Star Rating mouse click when hovering over stars

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm trying to have a mouse icon show up when I hover over the stars in this script using Bootstrap 4.

This is the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
<h4>Rate this product</h4>
<i class="fa fa-star fa-lg star-grey rateButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star fa-lg star-grey rateButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star fa-lg star-grey rateButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-star fa-lg star-grey rateButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star fa-lg star-grey rateButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>

<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="rating" name="rating" value="1">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="saveRating">
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript

```
    $( ".rateButton" ).click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('star-grey')) {
        $(this).removeClass('star-grey').addClass('star-highlight star-selected');
        $(this).prevAll('.rateButton').removeClass('star-grey').addClass('star-highlight star-selected');
        $(this).nextAll('.rateButton').removeClass('star-highlight star-selected').addClass('star-grey');
    } else {
        $(this).nextAll('.rateButton').removeClass('star-highlight star-selected').addClass('star-grey');
    }
    $("#rating").val($('.star-selected').length);  //count the num of star selected
});
```

This is how I want it to look https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLLUx.jpg

Comment: How is this question related to PHP?

Comment: Have a look at https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/dyMvoWg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to have a mouse icon show up when I hover over the stars in
> this script using Bootstrap 4

Showing mouse cursor to look like pointed hand (as in image) can be done using below css.

```
.rateButton {
   cursor: pointer
}
```

**Bootstrap way of doing it**

Add `role="button"`, then a cursor turns to hand. [Bootstrap reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/reboot/#pointers-on-buttons)

> Reboot includes an enhancement for role="button" to change the default
> cursor to pointer. Add this attribute to elements to help indicate
> elements are interactive. This role isn’t necessary for 
> elements, which get their own cursor change.

Your code will look like

`<i role="button" class="fa fa-star fa-lg star-grey rateButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Example

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<i role="button"> I am an i tag, hovering me should change the cursor to a hand</i>

<br />
<br />
<i> I am an i tag, but I dont have role="button" hovering me WILL NOT change cursor to a hand</i>
```

I prefer the first method if you don't want to edit the html

Comment: @Den.P I have updated answer with another method which might be useful

Comment: adding role="button" also works, lastly how do I get the stars to light up as I hover over them?

Comment: Add class `star-highlight` on mouse over event and remove class on move leave event

Comment: What I meant was to handle mouseover/mouseleave event and add/remove class `star-highlight` to the `i` tag, something similar to what you are doing in your click event.